# Best SQL for this query

Tags: sql, oracle

EDIT: So to make it easier we have two tables we need for this query.

1) Account_Cycle_Activity

2) Card_Account

The five columns we will be analyzing from 1) table are.

- ACCOUNT_ID
- ACTIVITY_TYPE_CDE
- CYCLE_CTR
- ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE
- CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT

and the column required to know from 2) table are

- ACCOUNT_ID
- CYCLE_CTR

The logic is:

> In ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY table find a row with ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE = '007' OR  '011' OR '021' and ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE = 'R12' and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT greater than $25 and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT between 1 to 900 **-- This is the first clause of my query.**
>
> And for the row which we just found above, its CYCLE_CTR column should be equal to the CYCLE_CTR column value from CARD_ACCOUNT table CYCLE_CTR minus 1. **-- This is the second clause**
>
> **Now this is the EXIST part of query**
>    If you find a row like this, and there are also no rows in the table for the same ACCOUNT_ID with the same ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE and same ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = 1 with CYCLE_CTR anywhere between the first row's CYCLE_CTR -6 through the first row's CYCLE_CTR - 1, report the account.

I came up with the below query

```
             SELECT *
             FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca 
             inner join card_account ca on ca.account_id = aca.ACCOUNT_ID
             WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE in('011', '021', '007') 
             and ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE= 'R12'
             and (CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT) > 25 
             and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT =1
             and aca.cycle_ctr = ca.cycle_ctr - 1
             and NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT aca2.ACCOUNT_ID
                         FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca2 
                         where ca.account_id = aca2.ACCOUNT_ID
                         and aca2.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE=aca.activity_type_code 
                         and aca2.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE= aca.activity_group_code
                         and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT =1
                         and aca2.cycle_ctr between aca.cycle_ctr - 6 and aca.cycle_ctr - 1);
```

Any ides on how to write it more efficiently to improve running time?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the requirements.  It would probably be helpful to post some (simplified) `CREATE TABLE` statements and some `INSERT` statements that populate the sample data you need along with the expected outputs and an explanation of why each account in the sample data is or is not included in the output.  Ideally, you could even do this on sqlfiddle and post a link.

Comment: i hope this is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a left (outer) join

```
SELECT aca.*, ca.* 
FROM card_account ca
inner join ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca  
        on aca.account_id = ca.ACCOUNT_ID
       and aca.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE in ('011', '021', '007') 
       and aca.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE = 'R12'           
       and aca.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = 1 
       and aca.cycle_ctr = ca.cycle_ctr - 1 
       and aca.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT > 25 
 left join ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca2
        on aca2.account_id           = aca.ACCOUNT_ID
       and aca2.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE   = aca.activity_type_code 
       and aca2.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE  = aca.activity_group_code
       and aca2.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = aca.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT
       and aca2.cycle_ctr      between aca.cycle_ctr - 6 and aca.cycle_ctr - 1           
where aca2.ACCOUNT_ID is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much! let me run this and report how long it takes to complete.

Comment: Just a question sholdnt this clause aca2.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT > 25 be for aca? instead of aca2?

Comment: Yes and it should not even  be in the left join

Comment: Thank you so much!! This seems to be working. I am sorry i cant give u an upvote, as i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Just one question, Is there a difference if we would have done " and  aca2.ACCOUNT_ID is null" instead of "where aca2.ACCOUNT_ID is null" in the last line of the query?

Comment: Give it a try.  If you think about it how can aca2.account_id  = aca.ACCOUNT_ID and be null?

Comment: Another question after a new requirement, if we want to add another join on this (to get an attribute in a different table), thus we would have to join on account_id of that table. Any clever way of doing this? as just adding another inner join after the first inner join and before left join is making it terribly slow.